# Remove a substring from each word of a string in C(if it contains it)

Tags: c

this is my first question on stackoverflow cause I have a certain difficulty in solving a substring removal. Some help would be greatly appreciated.
For example: char *string = "monkey peep through the keyhole" char *substring= "key". The output should be something like "mon peep through the hole". Anyone got any clue? I'm not really sure how you can compare each word with that substring without using strtok. Any suggestions would be really appreciated. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Why not post your attempt

Comment: use `strstr`. and make new result string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `strstr` and `memmove`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char s[] = "monkey peep through the keyhole";
  char k[] = "key";

  size_t m = strlen(k);  /* length of key                               */
  char *p;               /* pointer to start of key in string           */

  while (NULL != (p = strstr(s, k)))
  {
    char *q = p + m;       /* pointer to part after key in string       */
    size_t n = strlen(q);  /* length of part after key in string        */
    memmove(p, q, n + 1);  /* copy part after key in string
                              plus terminating '\0' (!) to start of key */
  }

  puts(s);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Works like a charm:

```
$ clang test.c

$ ./a.out 
mon peep through the hole
```

but is somewhat inefficient, because for every occurrence of the key we start searching from the start of string. Luckily, to avoid quadratic complexity, we only have to be a bit smarter:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char s[] = "monkey peep through the keyhole";
  char k[] = "key";

  size_t m = strlen(k);
  char *p = s;

  while (NULL != (p = strstr(p, k)))
  {
    char *q = p + m;
    size_t n = strlen(q);
    memmove(p, q, n + 1);
  }

  puts(s);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In the first iteration of the loop, we now start searching from the beginning of the string; in the following iterations, we start searching from the part after the previously removed occurrence of the key.

This approach now makes for a nice utility function:

```
char *remsubstrs(char *s, const char *k)
{
  size_t m = strlen(k);
  char *p = s;

  while (NULL != (p = strstr(p, k)))
  {
    char *q = p + m;
    size_t n = strlen(q);
    memmove(p, q, n + 1);
  }

  return s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight, the notes were really helpful to make me understand how I should think out the removal of the substrings. All the answers were generally great :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char *string = "monkey peep through the keyhole";
    char *substring= "key";
    size_t slen = strlen(substring);
    char *p, *s = string;
    while(*s){
        p = strstr(s, substring);
        if(p == NULL){
            puts(s);
            break;
        } else {
            while(s != p)
                putchar(*s++);
            s += slen;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char *string ="monkey peep through the keyhole";
char temp[512];
int i,j;

memset(temp , 0, 512);
for(i=0,j=0;i<strlen(string);i++)
{
    if(((string[i] == 'K')||(string[i] == 'k'))&&((string[i+1] == 'E')||(string[i] == 'e'))&& (string[i+2] == 'Y')||(string[i+2] == 'y') )
    {
        //do nothing
        i= i+2;
    }
    else
    {
        temp[j] = string[i];
        j++;
    }
}
printf("\n%s\n",temp);
```

You can use this logic with out using substr.